# Calling getFragmentManager() method from static view holder class of FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working on FirebaseUI RecyclerView and I want to create a dialog fragment when I click a list item. To create a new fragment, I have to call `getFragmentManager()` from static class. The error is given by IDE. I cannot pass parameters to static viewholder class because it is instantiated directly by Firebase recycler adapter.

Here is the code snippet of Adapter:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Course, CourseViewHolder>(
            Course.class,
            R.layout.list_item_course,
            CourseViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference
    ) {
```

The static class code is here:

```
private static class CourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {
        TextView textView;

    public CourseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_course_title_text_view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        CourseOperationFragment CourseOperationFragment = new CourseOperationFragment();
        CourseOperationFragment.show(manager, DIALOG_OPERATION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `Context` associated with a View by calling `getContext()` on the View.  Then, you can check to see if that Context is an `instanceof` `FragmentActivity`.  If it is, then you can cast the `Context` to `FragmentActivity`, and call methods on it to manipulate its fragments.

Comment: Thanks Pretty Amazed with logic.

Comment: This was crazy helpful, thank you! In case it helps others:  I used it because I have an Activity with a series of Fragments, gathering answers from the user on each Fragment. One of the Fragments has a Firebase RecyclerView where the user will choose from a list. From inside my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter I want to call a method in the calling Activity to move to the next Fragment after choosing an item. This solution is elegant and works great!